# android how to do drawing cube only one side of the curve? (with photo)

Tags: android, graphics, drawing

how to do drawing solid cube only one side of the curve? Like this photo.
i want `onDraw` on view.

```
<com.example.app.myCustomView ... />
```

[image]

Comment: And where is the `cube`?

Comment: @BobMalooga i want add to xml file. i can't drawing curve. cube is bottom in view. cube size no important. i want only one side with curve and 3 other side have line.

Comment: Still, a mockup screenshot of what you desire, would help. Because I still can't figure out what you want.

Comment: @BobMalooga ok, I'm going to draw a cube or rectangle is the only one of its sides **curved**. Using `mPath.cubicTo(x1,y1,..)` or other and so on. but i cant. In my mind is to see only the color orange. **Cube** or **rectangle** it does not matter. Curvature is important. plz help me

Comment: `Cube or rectangle it does not matter` ... So, may I suggest you a solution which uses **Cylinders** or **triangles**? Cubes and rectangles are very different figures. One is solid and the one is planar...

Comment: If you want to draw something like the picture above, it seems to me much conventient to use a VectorDrawable, so you can stretch it without quality loss.